# "downhill from there" - help to understand this joke

Tags: jokes

I watch this interesting clip today (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FLsWif6-Jfg), but I don't really understand the joke that he makes, which is:

A: We're going to mountain-climbing tomorrow, but I don't think you should climb to fast.

B: You don't think I should climb to fast? Why do you say that?

A: Well if you peak too soon, there will be all downhill from there.

Could you please help me to understand what makes people laugh in this joke? I think it must be funny, but I can't really get it.

Thanks

Comment: Both "peak too soon" and "downhill from there" are idioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a slightly elaborate pun.

1. Once you reach the peak, you can only descend the hill from there, so the rest of the path is all downhill.
2. If you touch the peak of your energies, the rest of the climb is going to be draining, a downer.
3. And simply the fact that going downhill could mean both *going down the hill,* as well as *losing your enthusiasm.*